# How can I compare null and string.Empty (or "") in fluent assertions?

Tags: c#, integration-testing, fluent-assertions

I have two objects of the same type, the type has a string field, in the first object the value is null, in the second one the value is "", how can I force fluent assesrtions to assume that this is correct?

Assesrtion itself:

```
callResult.ShouldBeEquivalentTo(centreResponse, 
                                opt => opt.Excluding(r => r.DateOpen));
```

here the exception is raised, stating the the expected value is null, the real one is "" (or vice versa)

Comment: What type are the objects? Can I assume that centre response is a string and opt is string[] or what?

Comment: Why would you want to treat `null` and the empty string as equivalent? That's rarely a good idea.

Comment: The objects are of type CentreResponse, which is a complex type, about the rules of comparison - that's the requirement, they come from different data sources, but in this particular context null and empty string are equal

Comment: With *field*, do you mean a C# field?

Comment: I mean a string typed property, sorry for misleading :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you can do is to override the behavior for properties of type `string` like this:

```
callResult.ShouldBeEquivalentTo(centreResponse, opt => opt
          .Excluding(r => r.DateOpen)
          .Using<string>(ctx => CompareStrings(ctx)).WhenTypeIs<string>());       

public void CompareStrings(IAssertionContext<string> ctx)
{
    var equal = (ctx.Subject ?? string.Empty).Equals(ctx.Expectation ?? string.Empty);

    Execute.Assertion
        .BecauseOf(ctx.Because, ctx.BecauseArgs)
        .ForCondition(equal)
        .FailWith("Expected {context:string} to be {0}{reason}, but found {1}", ctx.Subject, ctx.Expectation);
}
```

You can clean this up a bit by encapsulating the `CompareStrings` method in an implementation of `IAssertionRule`. See the `RelaxingDateTimeAssertionRule` in the unit tests of FluentAssertions [here](https://github.com/dennisdoomen/fluentassertions/blob/3e1a75f471b2480dc9ada44fca520bdefa06c174/FluentAssertions.Net40.Specs/EquivalencySpecs.cs#L3202).

You can add that custom assertion rule as the default for all assertions on your the type of your `callResult` variable, but I still have to add something to allow global defaults.